# node js puppeteer How do I scrape values ​from duplicate selector?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to scrape the value, but its selector is duplicate, I don't know how to solve.

It will always scrape the value of the one above.

here my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function scrape() {    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({})    const page = await browser.newPage()

   await page.goto('https://pantip.com/topic/34497907')    var element
= await page.waitForSelector("#comment-counter")    var text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element)    console.log(text)    browser.close() } scrape()
```

This is the part I want to scrape.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm4cp.png)

This is duplicate and above which I don't need it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFPQl.png)

[the web I scraped](https://pantip.com/topic/34497907)

I tried other methods I know already like xpath but it doesn't work because the part I will scrape is written in ajax the only way I know and it works now is to use this if there is another better way and about node js please recommend me :)​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote several solutions to your problem. The first is to get an array containing the contents of all the selectors we are looking for:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrape() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://pantip.com/topic/34497907");
  await page.waitForSelector("#comment-counter");

  const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#comment-counter")).map((el) => el.textContent.trim());
  });
  console.log(text);
  browser.close();
}
scrape();
```

Output:

```
[ 'สุดยอดความคิดเห็น', '169 ความคิดเห็น' ]
```

And in the second option, you can use a chain of selectors so that the one you are looking for is unique:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrape() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://pantip.com/topic/34497907");
  await page.waitForSelector("#comment-counter");

  const text = await page.$eval("#comments-counts #comment-counter", (el) => el.textContent);
  console.log(text);
  browser.close();
}
scrape();
```

Output:

```
169 ความคิดเห็น
```